# How can I get the author description's excerpt?

Tags: author, user-meta

```
<p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
```

We use the above to pull the author's description, but is there a way through which we can restrict or implement the word limit on the content pulled in the author's description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. You have to implement your own custom function to trim any content you wish. For example, this function will trim your content based on words:

```
function my_custom_excerpt ( $content, $limit = 20, $more = '...' ){                      
    return $data = wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $content ), $limit, $more );
}
```

Or this one will trim it based on characters:

```
function my_custom_excerpt( $excerpt, $limit = 20 ) {
    $charlength++;
    if ( mb_strlen( $excerpt ) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $excerpt, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            $output = mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            $output = $subex;
        }
        $output .= ' ...';
        return $output;
    } else {
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
<p><?php echo my_custom_excerpt( get_the_author_meta('description') , 20 ); ?></p>
```

Which will trim the author's description by 20 words/characters, based on your function.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't worked https://www.screencast.com/t/ULOnWhWivRt0 and https://www.screencast.com/t/EZ93JXnIG

Comment: Sorry I forgot to use `echo` in my code, updated the last code.

Comment: still didn't work. I am retaking the snapshot and send you. Maybe I am not writing function correctly.[Link 1](https://www.screencast.com/t/yjHtVHW6) and [Link 2](https://www.screencast.com/t/HrbaW3bGcKzT)

Comment: Where are you using this code? Try and use `echo get_the_author_meta('description')` instead and see if it outputs anything

Comment: working can we customize this? I mean put the word limit when we use this function with the echo?

Comment: I mean check if you have access to `get_the_author_meta('description')`, since it must be used within the loop

Comment: No No you are not getting my Point. Let me explain by example sir. [#1](https://www.screencast.com/t/XvFakOvdq) → this is Ok because here I want the same # of words that I write in the function that I created, but [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/pLoc2hcM) I want more words than the one example that I gave above. Did you get my point? two places and different number of word cutting.

Comment: I still don't understand the issue. What exactly has failed? Using `echo my_custom_excerpt( get_the_author_meta('description') , 20 );` will output 20 words, while changing 20 to 40 will output 40 words.